# Como fazer um sort de uma NodeList convertida para array?

Tags: javascript, array

Estou a tentar ordenar o array pela propriedade de estilo `order`.

Eis a minha tentativa:

```
var interval = setInterval(() => {
  var letterDivs = gameBox.getElementsByClassName("wordBox")[0].childNodes;

  console.log([...letterDivs]);

  [...letterDivs].sort((a, b) => {
    (a.style.order > b.style.order) ? 1 : -1;
  });
  console.log(letterDivs);
}, 300);
```

O último `console.log` não retorna a lista ordenada. Por quê? Como é que eu ordeno a lista?

Comment: `(a.style.order > b.style.order) ? 1 : -1;` => `return (a.style.order > b.style.order) ? 1 : -1;`?

Comment: Não colocarei essa observação na minha resposta porque sai um pouco do escopo da pergunta, mas eu repensaria a necessidade de se fazer o _sort_ da lista a cada 300 milissegundos. Operação de classificação de arrays são relativamente custosas para listas com muito elementos (complexidade grande-O `O(n log n)`), então verifique se não há como fazer esse tipo de coisa _fora_ do `setInterval`. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A propriedade `<elm>.style.order` retorna uma string com o valor definido na propriedade CSS `order` do elemento em questão.

Como é uma string, você deve se preocupar em convertê-la ao tipo adequado (número), uma vez que os operadores de comparação (como `>`) comparam strings de modo lexicográfico (então, por exemplo, `'11' < '100'` retornaria `false`, o que é um absurdo do ponto de vista numérico).

Posto isso, você pode fazer algo assim:

```js
const letterDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.wordBox > *');

const sorted = [...letterDivs].sort((a, b) => {
  const aNum = parseInt(a.style.order, 10);
  const bNum = parseInt(b.style.order, 10);
  
  // Irá jogar aqueles com `order` inválido para o final.
  if (Number.isNaN(aNum)) return 1;
  if (Number.isNaN(bNum)) return -1;
  
  // Ordena de ordem crescente:
  return aNum - bNum;
});

console.log(sorted.map((el) => el.textContent));
```

```html
<div class="wordBox">
  <span style="order: 4">4</span>
  <span style="order: 2">2</span>
  <span>Sem Order</span>
  <span style="order: 3">3</span>
  <span style="order: 1">1</span>
  <span style="order: dasdkaj">Order Inválido</span>
  <span style="order: 5">5</span>
</div>
```

<sup><sup>Note que utilizei o `map` ao final do exemplo anterior só para imprimir somente os textos de cada elemento no `console`. Mas isso mostra que a lista foi corretamente ordenada.</sup></sup>

Observe que também me preocupei em lidar com os possíveis casos em que o elemento não tiver uma propriedade `order` válida. Nesse caso, retornar-se-ia uma string qualquer ou uma string vazia. Como o JavaScript as interpreta como `NaN` mediante `parseInt`, verifico se são `NaN` e as ordeno dentro da função de comparação. Nesse caso, as ordeno para o fim da lista.

E a expressão `[...letterDivs].sort((a, b) => /* ... */)` **retorna** um novo array. Como utilizamos o *spread operator* dentro de um novo array literal, o `NodeList` `letterDivs` original não será modificado, já que só foi utilizado para fazer uma cópia para um novo array. Desse modo, precisamos atribuir o resultado da expressão em questão para uma nova variável. Nesse caso, criei uma nova variável chamada `sorted`.

E por fim sua função de comparação também não estava retornando nenhum valor. Utilizei o `return` para isso. [Saiba mais.](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Resultou! Mas eu não percebi como é que a diferença entre aNum e bNum ordena as orders por odem ascendente.

Comment: @InêsBarataFeioBorges, a função do `sort` recebe dois parâmetros (`a` e `b`). Se retornar um número menor que 1, coloca `a` em índice anterior a `b`. Se retornar 0, não muda. E se retornar número maior que 1, coloca `a` em índice posterior a `b`. Desse modo, a diferença faz exatamente isso (assumindo que sejam números). Quando subtraímos `b` de `a` (`a - b`), dizemos que, se `b` for maior que `a`, teremos um resultado negativo, de modo que `a` irá para _antes_ de `b`. Por outro lado, se `b` for menor que `a`, resulta-se em número positivo, no qual `a` será deslocado para depois de `b`.

Comment: Funciona se quiser ordenar de modo decrescente também, mas aí tem que se fazer `b - a`. :)